# Lifecycle - Android Studio

Tags: android

I created an app, am using google maps api, my app could track user location, and what i wanted to do is when i open the map screen with a button click and my app tracked user location but need sometime to track user depend on connection right? So when my app already track user location it will appear a Marker. How if i change map screen to other screen and then i back to the map screen it still showing marker without tracking again or run `track function`.

This is my `track function`

```
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            if(currLocationMarker != null){
                currLocationMarker.remove();

            }
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                String str = addressList.get(0).getSubLocality()+", ";
                //str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                str += addressList.get(0).getLocality();
                currLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                lokasisaya.setText(str);

                mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                        .center(latLng)
                        .radius(10000)
                        .strokeWidth(5)
                        .strokeColor(0x550000FF));


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude)).zoom(15).build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are removing the last `Marker` with `currLocationMarker.remove();` So I will assume you only need to maintain the last location.

The easiest way would be to use `SharedPreferences` to store the last location and then when your start the activity again chech to see if the location is available in the `SharedPreferences`.